# What is the shed bus in the Phenom 100?

Tags: aircraft-systems, electrical-system, embraer-phenom

I recently came across a part of the electrical system of aircraft named `SHED BUS`. I am specifically asking for the Embraer Phenom 100.

[image: Phenom 100 G1000 Electricity Status page]

[Source (Page 122)](http://static.garmincdn.com/pumac/190-00728-04_0A_Web.pdf), Added red square

- What is the `SHED BUS` for and what is it doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The shed bus powers non-essential aircraft systems. In the case of the phenom 100 this is things like the air conditioning, passenger power sockets and entertainment systems, the toilet and some lighting.

The shed bus is the first thing to lose power (be shed) should the aircraft not be generating enough electricity through, for example, a generator dropping offline.

Answer (score 8):

A SHED BUS is used to provide power to non-essential systems.  By powering off the shed bus, all non-essential loads can be removed in the case, for example, of a generator or engine failure with a single action rather than having to switch systems off one by one.  This might happen either automatically or via a cockpit switch or both.

Comment: On the Phenom 100 & 300, the Generator Control Units (one left and one right) control the contactors and will automatically disconnect the Shed Bus Contactor under certain conditions. I don't remember if there was an external control as well.

Answer (score 5):

Embraer aircraft have automated Electrical Distribution Logic (EDL).  The intent to to minimize crew workload. Part of the EDL protects the generators from being overloaded. It does that by disconnecting the Bus Tie Connector (BTC) for the Shed bus. This typically occurs when one generator (or more) goes off line.

The Shed bus itself provides power to non-essential systems, such as the galley and reading lights.